# In R, can't get results of regTermTest for gam model

Tags: r

I'm trying to compute Wald tests for interaction terms in a generalized additive model (gam in mgcv package) using R. The [documentation for regTermTest](http://faculty.washington.edu/tlumley/survey/html/regTermTest.html) says that the function takes a model with coef and vcov methods, but putting a gam model in doesn't seem to work. How can I get this method to work?  If it can't be done, is there another simple way to compute the same values in R?

lm model works

```
model <- lm(sysbp~pmper10*se_race4,data=mesa)
regTermTest(model,"pmper10:se_race4")
# Wald test for pmper10:se_race4
# in lm(formula = sysbp ~ pmper10 * se_race4, data = mesa)
# F =  3.940545  on  3  and  43621  df: p= 0.0080253
```

but gam model does not

```
model <- gam(sysbp~pmper10*se_race4,data=mesa)
regTermTest(model,"pmper10:se_race4")
# Error in solve.default(V) : 'a' is 0-diml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if you use the library `gam` but not `mgcv`.

The `regTermTest` function relies on extracting the `'assign'` attribute from the model matrix for a given model.

`aa <- attr(model.matrix(model), "assign")[okbeta]`

This object `aa` is used to construct the indices when creating `V`

A `gam` object from the package `mgcv` does not have this attribute. Using the example from `survey::regTermTest`

```
data(esoph)
 model1 <- glm(cbind(ncases, ncontrols) ~ agegp + tobgp * 
   alcgp, data = esoph, family = binomial())


regTermTest(model1,"tobgp")
```

If we use the package gam

```
library(gam)
 model2 <- gam(cbind(ncases, ncontrols) ~ agegp + tobgp * 
   alcgp, data = esoph, family = binomial())

 regTermTest(model2,"tobgp")
```

Gives the output

```
Wald test for tobgp
   in gam(formula = cbind(ncases, ncontrols) ~ agegp + tobgp * alcgp, 
     family = binomial(), data = esoph)
  F =  3.961947  on  3  and  67  df: p= 0.011609
```

While

```
library(mgcv)

model3 <- gam(cbind(ncases, ncontrols) ~ agegp + tobgp * 
   alcgp, data = esoph, family = binomial())


 regTermTest(model3,"tobgp")
```

Gives the error reported by the OP.

Comment: Thanks -- very helpful answer!  I ended up using the wald.test function in the aod package because I'd like to keep using mgcv.