# regTermTest in glmer model: how to resolve this "Error in beta %*% solve(V) "

Tags: r

`model <-glmer(npone ~ npone0 + race*time + (1 | ID), data=B2, family = binomial)`

`summary(model)`

`regTermTest(model,"time:race2")`

`Error in beta %*% solve(V) :  not-yet-implemented method for <list> %*% <dsyMatrix> In addition: Warning message: In coef.merMod(model, na.rm = FALSE) : arguments named "na.rm" ignored`

I tried from here:
[In R, can't get results of regTermTest for gam model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711811/in-r-cant-get-results-of-regtermtest-for-gam-model)

Data structure: in long format
npone & npone0:categorical: 2 categories
race: 3 categories
time: numeric
ID: categorical

I want: the overall p-value between race*time as shown here: https://vvanhee.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/equivalent-to-statas-lincom-and-test-or-testparm-in-r/